# How to run a for loop script in background via remote host using ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh

I have written an automation script in which I would like to SSH to the PC I want to send sipp messages with.
Here is a part of the automation script:

```
ssh `echo root@$UA_IP` "cd /opt/sipp.svn; killall -9 sipp; rm -rf registration_*.log;rm -rf receive_message_*.log; ./register.sh"
```

in the bash file register.sh I want to register different UAs in a while loop format. Here is a the bash file:

```
#!bin/bash
ulimit -n 65536
p=5060;
i=1;
while [ $i -le 100 ]; do
         ./sipp -sf registration.xml 192.168.10.4 -m 1 -r 1 -s UA$i -p $p -i 192.168.10.1 -trace_err </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 -bg;
          i=$(($i + 1))
          p=$(($p + 1))
done
```

The problem is only 50 UAs are registered, and others get error "This address is already taken". I don't have any idea what is going wrong.(I have set the port each time!)
Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. It was about the rtp socket. so I set it manually with -mp, also I added a sleep command in each loop, so the problem was fixed.
but after registering I want my users to listen on the ports registered, so I have another loop with sipp command. but this time any of the solutions I said don't work. :(
Does anyone have any idea?!
I really need help on this, thank in advance.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.